# Rendering Umbraco content after onChange event of select element

Tags: javascript, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a `select` element on my page. The options may be as follows:

```
<option value="1234">Contacts</option>
<option value="4567">Feedback</option>
<option value="7890">Addresses</option>
```

I want to have a section below the select which displays the content of an Umbraco page with the Id of the option value.

If I have an `onChange` event against the `select` element, how do I reload the Umbraco content based on the new Id value into my section? Do I have to use a Partial and pass the Id as a parameter? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a partial view and load into a `div` by dropdown `onchange` event.

**Example:**

**in Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Content(int contentId)  
{    
    var model = _service.GetContent(contentId) ;//Load content from DB
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

**script:**

```
$('#dropDownId').change( function() { 
     $.get('/Controller/Content/?contentId=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {   
         $('#divId').html(data);             
         $('#divId').fadeIn('fast');
     });    
});
```